# Qt with C#/.NET in Visual Studio v.09?

Tags: c#, .net, qt, qyoto

Do any of you have any experience working with [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(toolkit)) and C# in Visual Studio? Is it at all possible/easy to use together? I've searched for C# bindings for Qt, but all projects seem to have been abandoned.

I'm doing an application which *must* be coded in C#, which also needs to be able to run on [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)) (with [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software))). So, Qt was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Is this QT as in the "widget toolkit" or QT as in QuickTime?

Comment: I guess it's the development framework (a "widget toolkit" is only part of it). It should have been written "Qt" though. Side-note: For me, StackOverflow currently displays an ad for the Qt dev days right next to this question ;)

Comment: Visual Studio 09? Don't you mean either VS2009 or VS9.0?

Comment: are you simply referring to Qyoto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Qyoto](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Qyoto) project seems to be the way to go, and it seems to be still active. I don't have experience with it though.

Note that if the application is simple (i.e. doesn't use third-party components and no "hacks" to change behaviour), you can also give a simple WinForms application a try, which should run fine on Mono. And, well, if you don't actually need a GUI, you don't need anything except Mono. The Mono project itself, by the way, seems to favor Gtk# over Qt.

Comment: Seems OK to me too. Haven't worked with it yet, but as it's maintained by the KDE guys, it should be fine. Hopefully.

Comment: As far as I know, it uses the same code generator as other dynamic Qt implementations, like QtRuby. So until all of these fade away, this should be fine ;)