# Using C# to make Application for Maemo (convert code to QT)

Tags: c#, qt4, maemo

I want to make an application for my phone (Nokia N900) It uses the Maemo Platform, which is a Linux variant. Most applications are made with either QT or Python, i only have experience in C#, and am wondering if it is at all possible to convert C# to QT, or would i have to use something like Mono or Vala to write the code in C# and create the applications for the N900??

Cheers,

Brendan

Answer (score 4):

About "converting C# to Qt": they're not comparable: C# is a language, while Qt is a UI framework.

[Mono does run on Maemo](http://www.mono-project.com/Maemo) and while there are [Qt bindings for .Net/Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426335/qt-with-c-net-in-visual-studio-v-09), Mono uses [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits) as the default/recommended/supported UI framework.

Comment: heheheh thanks very much! Yeah im not confident enough in C# yet to learn a new lang, so i think ill try to become more proficient in that before i start on C++

Answer (score 2):

If you are already confident with C#/programming in general, then it should not be too much trouble to pick up a new set of tools. One size does not always fit all!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that exist a tool for convert C# code to the equivalent Qt/C++, Qt/Python, is something that is best done manually. It's best developed on a platform like a Mono for the N900 or find someone with knowledgeable in Qt able to carry out the work.

Note that Qt is the default platform for Nokia, if you want to install this application on other devices easily best using Qt.

Answer (score 1):

C# as a programming language is controlled by Microsoft. While Microsoft has stated that they will provide a "patent convenant" regarding C#, it is hard to believe them since they have been so eager to sue in the past. ;)

If you want to "convert" your C# app, you'll need to incorporate it into Mono. Mono is a 'cross-platform, opensource .NET development framework." http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Once you've got your app working in Mono, you'll need to interface into Maemo. There are a couple of routes to do this, but Qt is the most likely one to choose. It might be so much work to port your app to Qt that you decide to re-write it, fortunately Qt supports a number of programming languages so you may be able to find something similar to Mono if not Mono and C# itself.